# File globbing via goroutine

Tags: go

I have to glob a huge directory for certain files. This will take multiple seconds. Now using go, I of course would like to do the globbing in a way that I get back the result in a channel rather than having to wait for the whole glob to succeed.
Sadly I could not yet find something like that when searching. Is it available in go?

Comment: There is nothing built in, but of course you could write your own function using `os.File.Readdirnames`.

Answer (score 0):

There is the built-in function [`filepath.Glob`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob) which you can use to glob-search files in a directory, but of course it does the glob all at once synchronously. If you want results over a channel, you'll have to do something yourself, but it should not be terribly difficult combining [`filepath.Match`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match) which does glob handling, and [`filepath.Walk`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk) which walks a directory structure (this is sort of what `filepath.Glob` does, [though it uses recursion rather than `Walk`](https://golang.org/src/path/filepath/match.go?s=5609:5664#L224)).